# What is the maximum number of friend invites?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

For some people that I try to send a friend invite to, it says that they've received the maximum number of friend invites, yet they still have space on their friends list, so it is not that their friends list is full. How can I tell when I've received the maximum amount of friend invites? Are they the ones sitting in mail?

Answer (score 1):

50 unanswered requests / unopened mails is the mailbox limit.